Fetch data is showing in console but I can't get it to display on my site - react.js
I'm trying to show the movie images and movie titles from Movies Database on my site to browse. I don't have much experience with React and not sure what I'm doing wrong or what needs to be changed to get the data to show on the site.
I'm using fetch and useState. Fetch must be working correctly as it's showing in the console.
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  let url = 'https://moviesdatabase.p.rapidapi.com/titles';

  function apiGet() { 

  const fetchData = fetch(url, { method: 'Get', headers: {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': '',
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'moviesdatabase.p.rapidapi.com'
  }})
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json);
      setData(json);
    });
  };

return (

<>
    My API <br/>
    <button onClick={apiGet}>Fetch API</button>
    <br />

    <div>
        {[data].map((item) => {
          return (
                <img key= "{item.id}" src={item.primaryImage} />

          )
})}
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

I've deleted the api key to share this.

{data.length > 0 && data.map((item) =>
You can change this line.

So according to your state, data is expected to be an array. Therefore, if your API request returns an array, you can directly iterate over it in your JSX:
<div>
  {data.map((item) => (
    <img key={item.id} src={item.primaryImage} />
  ))}
</div>

Also, please note that in your code, key="{item.id}" is enclosed in quotes, making it a string literal. As a result, the same key will be assigned to all images.

Thanks for your reply! Noted on the quotes. When I use that code I get an error saying data.map is not a function - do you know why that could be?

It means data isn't an array. Make sure the response from the API is in the expected array format.
